# About the Core Data base design

Tags: ios, database, database-design, core-data

I'm devellopping an IOS app for one month and I feel like I'm ready to create the data base. So as I've learn at school, I took my pencil and start to create my data base design.

Then I start to read the core data guides, in fact I've already used core data but it was in smaller projects. So I read about the Managed Object and they seems to always fit exactly the model object (MVC) of the applications.

So this is my question. Does I have to write the Managed Objects as an sqlLite data base shema (with split tables etc...) and start to write some methods to construct my model objects from thoses tables ? OR should I write the managed object exaclty as the Model objects ? They will be reconstructed much easier but won't it be less efficient?

To ask it in an other way: do the core data base shema should looks like an sqlLit data base with split tables or should it looks like as a set of my Model Objects?

I hope my question is clear.

Thank you,

Alexandre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use core data, you should not, in any way interact with the SQLite database. The exact way core data stores the objects should be opaque to you.

There is nothing to stop you writing the database layer yourself. You can make and interact with an SQLite database directly and do everything yourself.

General advice is that core data has been around a long time and any issues you encounter making objects and keeping them in sync across threads, caching and speed of access have already been encountered and fixed by the core data team. Save yourself some work, Stand on the shoulders of giants and use Core Data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I direclty create my managed objects as they are and I don't split them into different tables as I generaly do with an sql data base?

Comment: if you would normally make a new table it probably means that in core data you should make a new entity and set up a relationship between entities. Core Data will take care of the rest

Comment: Thank you, that was the anwer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you have tagged your question with iOS, one of the best things you can do, is to forget about traditional model relationship techniques you have previously used in relational database (especially the one used with web applications), and structure your NSManagedObject graph depending also on the use you are doing in your UI.

This is especially true when you have something like UITableView. For example, if you are showing only title and description in a table cell, and then you have detail view with all the data, it has perfect sense to model your graph like this:

```
EntityMain {
  NSString *title,
  NSString *desc,
  // other that may be useful, such as a state...ecc
  toOne relationship --> EntityDesc
}

EntityDesc {
  NSString *prop1,
  NSString *prop2,
  ......
  ....
  NSString *prop 20
}
```

Where EntityMain is retrieved, say, by a NSFetchedResultsController, while in the detail view you can retrieve the whole object. In this case you are not fetching more than necessary, and performance will benefit.

This will also help you in case you want to have a separated NSManagedObjectContext for detail editing.

Comment: Thank you, I unfortunately can't accept two answers but it is a very nice explanation.